# How to handle unicode language in python

Tags: python, unicode

I am writing a `Python` + `Selenium` script to scrap Linkedin site.
I read the profile summary using this statement, which works properly:

```
profileDescription = profile.find_element_by_xpath("div/div[1]").text
```

My problem is with the non english data coming from the site.
I am writing the data scrapped from the site to an excel using this code:

```
with open('search.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:
    self.liSearchOutWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    self.liSearchOutWriter.writerow([profileDescription])
```

Whenever description contains non-english data, it does not display properly in the excel. I read through `unicode` and `utf8` resources, but could not get a grip on it.

Can someone help me understand how I should modify my code in order to display non english data properly?

Comment: Which version of python are you using? (And, uh, if you're using python2, can you switch to using python3?)

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and I cannot use Python 3

Comment: Consider opening the file with `codecs.open`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.X this is supported out of the box:

```
 import csv
 with open('search.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         print(row)
```

If you're in Python 2.X there is a drop-in library for csv that supports unicode:
[unicode-csv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv)

```
import unicodecsv
with open('search.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    unicodecsv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8'
```

Comment: I am getting this error after using `unicodecsv`. `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 0: invalid
ontinuation byte`